# Recursion fails for Large N

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I encountered this question.

Let us consider a game, which has a board 3 cells wide by **N** cells tall. Each cell has a
number between 0 and 99 written on it. You can enter the board on any
cell of the top row and exit from any cell of the bottom. You
can move from a cell to any adjacent cell (diagonally or directly beneath) in the row below.
When you are at a cell, you must either add or subtract the number written
on the cell.
For the given value X, what is the smallest number greater than or equal to
X, that you can obtain from this process?

Input
The first line of input contains a single integer, the number
of test cases. The first line of each test case contains two integers, **N** and **X**.
The next **N** lines each contain three
space-separated numbers, the cell values you must add or subtract.

Output

For each set of input print the smallest number greater than or equal to
X.

Sample Input

```
2
3 0
83 86 77
15 93 35
86 92 49
3 59
83 86 77
15 93 35
86 92 49
```

Sample Output

```
2 59
```

Note:

2 = 86 - 35 - 49

59 = 86 - 93 + 86

This is my solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class n3 {

    static int min;
    static int result;
    static int X;
    int go = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            // sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));

            int T = sc.nextInt();
            for (int tc = 0; tc < T; tc++) {



                int N = sc.nextInt();
                min = sc.nextInt();

                result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

                int m[][] = new int[N][N];
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        m[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                    }
                }

                n3 game = new n3();
                game.start(m, N);
                System.out.println(result);

            }
        }
    }

    private void start(int[][] m, int N) {

        int x = min;
        compute(m, -1, 0, 0, N);
        // compute(m, -1, 0, -x, N);
        compute(m, -1, 1, 0, N);
        compute(m, -1, 2, 0, N);

    }

    private boolean isSafe(int[][] m, int row, int col, int N) {

        if (row >= 0 && col >= 0 && row < N && col < 3) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void compute(int[][] m, int x, int y, int value, int N) {
        // System.out.println(value + " " + x + " " + y);

        if (go == 1) {
            return;
        }

        if (x == N - 1 && value >= min) {
            if (value < result) {
                result = value;
            }

            if (value == min) {
                result = min;
                go = 1;
            }
            return;
        }

        if (isSafe(m, x + 1, y - 1, N)) {
            compute(m, x + 1, y - 1, value + m[x + 1][y - 1], N);
            compute(m, x + 1, y - 1, value - m[x + 1][y - 1], N);
        }

        if (isSafe(m, x + 1, y, N)) {
            compute(m, x + 1, y, value + m[x + 1][y], N);
            compute(m, x + 1, y, value - m[x + 1][y], N);
        }

        if (isSafe(m, x + 1, y + 1, N)) {
            compute(m, x + 1, y + 1, value + m[x + 1][y + 1], N);
            compute(m, x + 1, y + 1, value - m[x + 1][y + 1], N);
        }

    }
}
```

However this fails when N is large.  Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: What is an n 3 square board?

Comment: When you describe this game, consider that (a) we don't know the game, and (b) we can't read your mind.

Comment: Failing how? A stacktrace or the output you expect & receive would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Each call to compute (m, x, ...) makes either four or six calls to compute (m, x+1, ...). So if you increase N by 1, the work increases at least by a factor 4. Your code just runs forever.

For each row and column keep track of the set of integers that you might have as your points at that point. Then in the recursion, check whether you have calculated the points for that row / column already and don't do it again.

Comment: can you give some example?

Answer (score 0):

@gnasher729 has the right idea.  Here's a short description with your given example.

Start at the top of the board.  For each square, move and compute the possible total at each square.  Fill these into a list of lists; the "status" at this row looks something like:

```
left:  [-83, 83],
mid:   [-86, 86],
right: [-77, 77]
```

Now move to row 2.  The middle position can connect to each of the 3 squares; the ends can connect to only the nearer 2.  Apply the add & subtract operations to each of the squares.  For instance, the left square (15) can be "fed" by either the left (83) or middle (86) position.  This time, I'll work it out in two steps:

```
left:  [-83-15, 83-15, -83+15, 83+15, -86-15, 86-15, -86+15, 86+15], 
mid:   [-83-93, 83-93, -83+93, 83+93, -86-93, 86-93, -86+93, 86+93, -77-93, 77-93, -77+93, 77+93]
right: [-86-35, 86-35, -86+35, 86+35, -77-35, 77-35, -77+35, 77+35]
```

When we do the math, we get the entries:

```
[-98, 68, -68, 98, -101, 71, -71, 101],
[-176, -10, 10, 176, -179, -7, 7, 179, -170, -16, 16, 170],
[-121, 51, -51, 121, -112, 42, -42, 112]
```

Continue to work your way down the rows of the table.  Since you don't care about the path, just the sum itself, you don't have to keep track of all the subtotals -- just the left, middle, and right sets for the most recent row.

When you reach the bottom, combine the three lists, sort into ascending order, and then take the first number that's at least as large as **X**.